# Can you make a server side httprequest that mimicks a html form post?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

When you perform a HTML POST to a page, it does this:

1. validates based on your form fields
2. redirects the user to a different url and responds with a authentication cookie and another cookie.

If I create a simple html page with a form on it, it works fine and I get redirected.

Would it be possible to do this on the server side only?  If the endpoint reads the form fields, and then redirects with cookies then I guess not right since the server side won't have any notion of the cookies?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you to post server side:

```
    WebRequest request = default(WebRequest);
    request = WebRequest.Create(your_url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-encoded";
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream);

    //'// Read the Response
    WebResponse wr = request.GetResponse;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream);
    var ReturnValue = sr.ReadToEnd.Trim;
```

You can set cookies on the post like this:

```
request.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie) = "MyCookie=value;";
```

Comment: I'm referring to setting the cookies from the response of the http call, not my cookies.